# VPN plugin for 14.04

Tags: openvpn

Where do I find then install vpn plugin for ubuntu 14.04? I want to install a vpn but can not find a plugin for it. I have read through many questions but not found out where to get a plugin for vpn.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way to install is from the terminal using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager-openvpn-gnome
```

You will need to restart your network manager:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

To setup a new connection you can goto Settings > Networking and then click on the plus symbol on the bottom left and select VPN, from the following screen you will be asked to select your VPN type and from there you can select openvpn and the complete the details to configure the connection.