# how to configure a vpn service on ubuntu

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I want to make my navigation in secure way and I won't buying  vpn services as expressvpn etc.. openvpn can do this by installing on the PC that I use to navigate?

If yes can you link me any guide to configure it ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: might this help: [/609772/vpn-plugin-for-14-04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/609772/vpn-plugin-for-14-04)?

Comment: btw are you asking for openvpn's server?

Comment: @Ravan I don't know if I need to configure a vpn server. I want to use only my single pc to connect in vpn.  What I need to do this ?

Comment: please see linked question....

Comment: also this one http://askubuntu.com/questions/187284/how-to-configure-vpn-settings

Comment: Visit the official [Ubuntu Help Community](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VPNClient) you'll get the detailed info here

Comment: @jaysheelutekar all the officila links are covered in linked post..=)

Comment: @Ravan ok but I have to follow the guide for VPN setup in Ubuntu – General introduction here or Setting up an OpenVPN server here ? 
How I said I don't need to connect other device on vpn but only a single pc